# Separate items in tuples in list when writing to csv

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, csv, io

I am trying to write items in a list that contains 5 tuples that each have 5 items( 1 string 4 integers). I am trying to write them to a csv file. I keep getting each tuple in 1 cell despite using the `delimiter = ','`. What I would like to do is put each tuple in a separate row and each item in these tuples in their own cell.
Here is the code I am using, and the list. This function is inside of an object class and all else is working fine.

The code:

```
[('Endurance', 112, 150, 121, 136), ('Tempo', 152, 190, 138, 142),
 ('Threshold', 192, 210, 144, 150), ('VO2', 212, 240, 152, 155),
 ('Anaerobic', 242, 300, 156, 161)]

def writeCSV(self,l):

    with open('tz.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter = ',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(l)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writer.writerows()` to write a whole list of rows:

```
import csv
lst = [('Endurance', 112, 150, 121, 136), ('Tempo', 152, 190, 138, 142),
       ('Threshold', 192, 210, 144, 150), ('VO2', 212, 240, 152, 155),
       ('Anaerobic', 242, 300, 156, 161)]

def write_csv(lst):

    with open('tz.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter = ',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerows(lst)

write_csv(lst)
```

The file content:

```
"Endurance","112","150","121","136"
"Tempo","152","190","138","142"
"Threshold","192","210","144","150"
"VO2","212","240","152","155"
"Anaerobic","242","300","156","161"
```